# parsing json file containing arrays and objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I have a large json file which has 5 child nodes, 4 of which are objects and one which is an array.

When i cycle through them i hit the array with my code below and it fails, complaining the object is not a 'jObject' type. If i put JArray it fixes it but im not sure how to check beforehand if the json is a jObject or jArray?

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonChildObjectsArray.Length; i++)
{
    string jsonCategoryContents = json[jsonChildCategorysArray[i]].ToString();
    jsonChildObjectsArray[i] = jsonCategoryContents;        
    JObject jsonCategoryObject = JObject.Parse(jsonCategoryContents); 
           //error's here on 5th element as it is a jArray type.
}
```

Comment: Can you make a class that models the whole file? Then just let the parser do the work of figuring out how to decode it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the most i can hope to assume is that it is well formed.

Comment: @Fearghal, if that's really the case then I'd break this into multiple steps. Parse the string you get that may or may not be well-formed yourself. You can parse it into JSON and then use a parser, or just parse it yourself into the destination object you need. If you can't really rely on the schema being correct or even the content well-formed, using tools that expect that will always be extremely frustrating.

Comment: Thx a mil, i can def expect it to be well formed, just not to be consistent.

Comment: @Fearghal, if you have any control over the source of the JSON then you could add in schema definition variables that tell you what type of random variable to parse next. It does add some overhead to the file. It is usually better to break these up into specific JSON schema types before transmitting.

Comment: ok i'll def look into that? Have you got an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `JToken.Parse` instead:

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse(jsonCategoryContents);

if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object) 
{
    JObject jsonCategoryObject = token.ToObject<JObject>();
}
else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
    JArray jsonCategoryArray = token.ToObject<JArray>();
}
```